# adding item to store in swing java using submit button

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I created a store that saves records of person instances.
when adding the employees from CLI it works and the store increments, when using swing and CLI for debug i can see the new record but the increment is not done !

```
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Store recordStore;
            recordStore = new Store(1);

                // here add the submitting text
                Employee em = new Employee("mn",'M', new Date(18,12,1991), "025", new Date(2,5,2009));

                if (!Store.isFull())
                    {

                    recordStore.add(em);
                    recordStore.displayAll();
                    System.out.println("Current size of store is " + Store.getCount());
                    }

                else
                {   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The store seems to be full, please save it, and create a new one!"); }
```

The store add function

```
    public void add(Person p)
{
    // person p is added to array

    list[count++] = p;
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void add(Person p)
{
  // person p is added to array
  list[count++] = p;
}
```

If above function is defined in the `Store` class then you are initializing a new instance

```
Store recordStore;
recordStore = new Store(1);
```

every time. So your list count will always be 1. So as `Hovercraft Full Of Eels` has suggested 
move that outside the `ActionListener` class and change code accordingly.

Or else use a `static count` that stores the count of `records of person instances` that you have added.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that your problem is that you're creating a new Store instance each time the ActionListener code is run. Perhaps you want to create a Store instance once in the class and add to it in the ActionListener.